# Finding the longest and the shortest lists within a list in Python

Tags: python, list, max, min

I need to print the lists which have minimum and maximum number of items in a list.

For example if I have:

```
total_list = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

I need to return the lists with a minimum and maximum lengths. How can I do it?

Output could be something like:

```
total_list[0] and total_list[2]
```

Comment: How could we possibly tell you what you did wrong if you don't show us what you did?

Comment: If you already got to the point where you have the len of each list item, then you are almost done. You just need to set an initial min/max value then compare it to the len values you have, and if it's `>` or `<`, store those index numbers and return them once the loop is complete

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`max` and `min` function in python accepts a `key` argument that will find the max of an iterable based on what defined as a key. so, try this:

```
max(total_list, key=len)
```

then you can use `total_list.index` to find those indexes

Comment: What if there are multiple longest or shortest lists? Your code won't work in that case.

Answer (score 2):

```
total_list = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1,2,3,4,5]]

print('total_list[{0}] and total_list[{1}]'.format(total_list.index(min(total_list, key=len)), total_list.index(max(total_list, key=len))))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py x.py
total_list[0] and total_list[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `min( iterable, key=len)` ([min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)/[max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)) is easiest. If you like to go through your list yourself, you can do this like so:

```
tl  = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1,2,3,4,5]]

# init shortest and longest to 1st element of list
# use a tuple to store:  ( listdata, length, position in original list )
shortest = longest = (tl[0], len(tl[0]), 0)

# iterate over remaining elements
for pos_act,act in enumerate(tl[1:],1): # start enumerate on 1 to fix position due slicing
    # get actual length
    len_act = len(act)

    # is it larger then current largest?
    if len_act > longest[1]:
        longest = (act,len_act, pos_act)

    # is it shorter then current shortest?
    if len_act < shortest[1]:
        shortest = (act, len_act, pos_act)

print ("Shortest: {} with len {} on position {}".format(*shortest))
print ("Longest: {} with len {} on position {}".format(*longest))
```

Output:

```
Shortest: [1, 2, 3] with len 3 on position 0
Longest: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] with len 5 on position 2
```

Doku:

- [enumerate(iterable[,start_value])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)